# Scala playframework - object java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect is not a value

Tags: scala, playframework

[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z3Ou.png) <--- when I use function update, I want to redirect to BooksController.index()  but when i try it I have an error: object java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect is not a value. Can somebody help?

BooksController:

```
val bookForm = Form(
    tuple(
      "id" -> number,
      "title" -> text,
      "price" -> number,
      "author" -> text
    )
  )


def edit(Id: Int) = Action {
    val book: Book = Book.findById(Id)
    Ok(views.html.edit())
  }


def update(Id: Int) = Action {
          implicit request =>
          val (id, title, price, author) = bookForm.bindFromRequest.get
          val book: Book = Book.findById(id)
          book.id = id
          book.title = title
          book.price = price
          book.author = author
          Redirect(routes.BooksController.index())
      }
```

My edit view:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Form example</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" autocomplete="on">
    Id: <input type="text" name="id"><br><br>
    Title: <input type="text" name="title"><br><br>
    Price:<input type="text" name="price"><br><br>
    Author: <input type="text" name="author"><br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Routes:

```
GET     /books                      controllers.BooksController.index
GET     /books/create               controllers.BooksController.create
GET     /books/:id                  controllers.BooksController.show(id: Int)

POST    /books/create               controllers.BooksController.save

GET     /books/edit/:id             controllers.BooksController.edit(id: Int)
POST    /books/edit                 controllers.BooksController.update
```

Error:
    play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[object java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect is not a value]
            at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
            at play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException$.apply(PlayExceptions.scala:34)
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$taskFailureHandler$1(PlayReload.scala:33)
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.taskFailureHandler(PlayReload.scala:28)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compileFailure(PlayReload.scala:24)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.$anonfun$compile$3(PlayReload.scala:51)
            at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
            at play.sbt.run.PlayReload$.compile(PlayReload.scala:51)

Comment: I answered your question, in the last question you posted. If that answer solves your problem delete this question, as it is a duplication of your last question.

Comment: The answer didn't solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at the `Redirect` definition:

> ```
>  /**
>    * Generates a redirect simple result.
>    *
>    * @param url the URL to redirect to
>    * @param status HTTP status
>    */
>   def Redirect(url: String, status: Int): Result = Redirect(url, Map.empty, status)
> ```

So your `Redirect` should be:

```
Redirect("/books")
```

**Update**

Ok, after you added the error, you error seems to be because of `bookForm.bindFromRequest.get`. So, if you look at the form in your html and your defined form:

`id` needs to be an input of type `number` and not `text`, as well as the `price`.

Comment: @Michael copy/paste your full error, at the end of your question.

Comment: "object java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect is not a value" And Redirect is marked. When i get to home i will do screen short.

Comment: @Michael updated the answer. Change either your html or your form definition for this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so my friend resolve the problem. My mistake was in routes. I forgot to add id:

```
POST    /books/edit/:id            controllers.BooksController.update(id: Int)
```